# testing android app on real devices

Tags: android, beta-testing

i have just single android phone, but I'll like to test my application on as many devices is possible. Do you have any idea about how can I do that?

Comment: You'll have to buy them in that case. The only alternative is emulator. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html) to know how you can achieve it. Also see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)

Comment: The hardest is performance stress testing, you can emulate it by using a low end phones though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many services designed for testing apps on multiple real devices. Here are just a few:

http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/android.html

http://www.deviceready.com/

https://www.lesspainful.com/

All of these services will cost you, and you will have to set up tests that they will run, but they will execute your tests on multiple devices in both orientations and Lesspainful will even send you screen shots to show you the difference between your tests on the different devices.

Comment: As a further to this it is much better to test your apps with real users. Testflight is a great iPhone beta deployment solution and similar exist for Android: http://hockeykit.net/ http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Nothing is quite as good as getting an app into a users hand and watching them use it.

Comment: Hey @Michael thanks a million for the three links. (DeviceReady seems to be not in business yet.)  Let me ask you something, those seem to be more AUTOMATED services.  (Eg with LessPainful you use calabash or something to remotely get screenshots etc.) I've really been struggling to find essentially a "manual" testing house. You send them a build and they test it on 50 devices manually and you just talk to them etc.  As an Android dev, you may know something like this? A totally mystery to me in iOS-land as I don't know the Android business scene!!!!  Thanks in advance if you see this note,

Answer (score 2):

first trying on different emulator setting will server the purpose also. (different screen sizes, ram, cpu, resolution) and stuff. After you are little satisfied with your app, then try asking your friends if they are willing to install your cool application.

or just go buy used android phones over craigslist or something

Answer (score 2):

my case is similar as yours what I do is that I test the basic functionality on one set that I have and to see designs I use emulators

best option would be to create the designs programatically using layout params in that way you can make a app run on ldpi set to a Tablet